# Display specific days in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have an array which contain name of the days which should be highlighted which I am getting from database.The days which are not in the arrays need not be selected by the user.I have done like this.Unfortunately its not working.

```
var day_array = ['Sun','Tue','Thu'] //these days should only be selected by user
$("#collection_date").datepicker(
        {
         minDate:new Date($("#startdate").val()),
         maxDate:new Date($("#enddate").val()),
         beforeShowDay:function(date){
             var day = date.getDay(),Sun=0,Mon=1,Tue=2,Wed=3,Thu=4,Fri=5,Sat=6;
             console.log(day);
             for(var i=0;i<day_array.length;i++)
             {
                 if ($.inArray(day, day_array) == -1)
                {
                    return [false];
                }
             }
             return [true];
         }
        }
    );
```

I need to make a datepicker where user can select only Sunday,Tuesday and Thursday.

EDIT:When I am making the final return statement to false,none of the day are highlighted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make an array of day names to match your array against and do it like this:

```
var day_array = ['Sun', 'Tue', 'Thu'] //these days should only be selected by user
var week = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
$("#collection_date").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        if ($.inArray(week[day], day_array) == -1) {
            return [false];
        } else {
            return [true]
        }
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dxuq0op4/)**